# How to display User's data using Session variables from login page?

Tags: php, session, mysqli, passwords

I need help regarding using Session variables, I want to display Logged In User's data on the next screen.
This is **Login.php**

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
        $link = mysqli_connect("shareddb-h.hosting.stackcp.net", 
"StudentDetails-33314e4f", "2kg3dvardk", "StudentDetails-33314e4f");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

            die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

        } 
        $username = "";
        $LoginEmail = (isset($_POST['LoginEmail']) && 
!empty($_POST['LoginEmail'])) ? $_POST['LoginEmail'] : false;
        $LoginPassword = (isset($_POST['LoginPassword']) && 
!empty($_POST['LoginPassword']))? $_POST['LoginPassword']: false;


        $query ="SELECT `Email`,`ID`, `Password` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE 
Email='$LoginEmail' AND Password='$LoginPassword'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);    
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count == 1 )
        {
            $query ="SELECT `ID` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE Email='$LoginEmail' 
AND Password='$LoginPassword'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $array = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            $_SESSION['userid'] =$array ;
            header("location: StudentInformation.php");
        }
        else {

            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Invalid username or password";

        }


    ?>
```

This is **STudentInfo** Page on which I want to display the data.

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
        $link = mysqli_connect("shareddb-h.hosting.stackcp.net", 
"StudentDetails-33314e4f", "2kg3dvardk", "StudentDetails-33314e4f");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

            die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

        }
        $query = "SELECT `FirstName` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE ID = 
'".$_SESSION['userid[ID]']."'";
        $FN = mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $FirstName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($FN);
        print_r($FirstName);
?>
```

I tried everything and it seems that mysqli_fetch_assoc is not working in Login.php and StudentInfo page. Please help me over this or if you have any other alternative, it is welcome!

Comment: Well this is incorrect: `$_SESSION['userid[ID]']` ... change to `$_SESSION['userid']` ... and this would then have to be adjusted for your use of `$_SESSION['userid'] = $array;`. So ultimately: `$_SESSION['userid'][0]['ID']` (because for some reason you are `while` looping on a single result row =p

Comment: And then the obligatory copy/paste responses about "Do not store plain text passwords in a database... use password_hash and password_verify" and "You are wide open to sql injection attacks with those non-prepared statements" ;) And, you will definitely want to change your database user/pass now that you pasted it for the world to see.

Comment: I hope that what you posted aren't actual login credentials. If so, you had better go and **change them now.**

Comment: Enable error reporting and use `mysqli_error($link)` on the queries, then tell us what those errors were, if any.

Comment: I don't understand why you search for a user, then... search for the same user. Just use the result from the first search to set the ID into the session. And get rid of the `while` loop, as that query *should* only return one user if you have proper constraints in place.

Comment: Your code is open to a serious SQL injection, use a prepared statement. Also, do not store plain text passwords, use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.

Comment: @IncredibleHat *Heh*. I find it rather odd that the discussion notice shows up. The system thinks we are chatting with each other, which in a way we are; just *to* the OP who appears to have gone "AWOL".

Comment: Hello I have made following changes in login.php
if($count == 1 )
            {
               $query ="SELECT `ID` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE Email='$LoginEmail' AND Password='$LoginPassword'";
             $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
               $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
               
               $_SESSION['userid'] =$array['ID'] ;
     header("location: StudentInformation.php");
            }

Now its not even heading towards StudentInformation.php

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Hello sir, Do not worry, this is not my actual project, I am making a piece of it. i want to run this part first and then move on. Also, please help me on what I had to do in order to enable error reporting. ?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I have now removed while loop and have made changes which I have mentioned in earlier comments. Now its not heading to StudentInformation.php page.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code you have to change your code like this:

```
  <?php 
    session_start();
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "db"); //take care, you should avoid posting sensitive data 

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

            die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

        } 
        $username = "";
        $LoginEmail = (isset($_POST['LoginEmail']) && 
!empty($_POST['LoginEmail'])) ? $_POST['LoginEmail'] : false;
        $LoginPassword = (isset($_POST['LoginPassword']) && 
!empty($_POST['LoginPassword']))? $_POST['LoginPassword']: false;


        $query ="SELECT `Email`,`ID`, `Password` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE 
Email='".$LoginEmail."' AND Password='".$LoginPassword."'"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);    
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if($count == 1 )
        {
            $query ="SELECT `ID` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE Email='".$LoginEmail."' 
AND Password='".$LoginPassword."'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $array = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $array[] = $row;
            }
            $_SESSION['userid'] =$array['userid'] ; //instead of saving the complete row, you can save just the variable
            header("location: StudentInformation.php");
        }
        else {

            $_SESSION['errMsg'] = "Invalid username or password";

        }


    ?>
```

And then in your second code you just have to replace your query

```
 $query = "SELECT `FirstName` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['userid']."'";
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The 2nd part of code stands to be correct. *But*, the first part is wrong. You're asking the OP to change the quotes. What they have now is valid. Both `'$var'` and `'".$var."'` do the same thing.

Comment: Hello Sir, Thank you for responding so quick. Although it didn't worked for me. It is not showing any error but resulting in a blank page and not even heading towards StudentInformation.php @Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

first of all thank you all of you for giving your consideration. I found answer for my question and want to post desired changes.
I just changed above code a little bit and made it simple and working

```
if($count == 1 )
    {
        $query ="SELECT `ID` FROM `StudentInfo` WHERE Email='$LoginEmail' 
AND Password='$LoginPassword'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $_SESSION['userid'] =$row['userid'] ;
        header("location: StudentInformation.php");
    }
```

And in second part of code : print_r($FirstName['FirstName']);